# C++ Bits in 64 bit integer

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

Hello I have a struct here that is 7 bytes and I'd like to write it to a 64 bit integer.  Next, I'd like to extract out this struct later from the 64 bit integer.

Any ideas on this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

struct myStruct
{
        unsigned char a;               
        unsigned char b;
        unsigned char b;
        unsigned int someNumber;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    myStruct * m = new myStruct();
    m->a = 11;
    m->b = 8;
    m->c = 12;
    m->someNumber = 30;

    printf("\n%s\t\t%i\t%i\t%i\t%i\n\n", "struct", m->a, m->b, m->c, m->someNumber);

    unsigned long num = 0;

    // todo: use bitwise operations from m into num (total of 7 bytes) 

    printf("%s\t\t%i\n\n", "ulong", num);

    m = new myStruct();

    // todo: use bitwise operations from num into m;

    printf("%s\t\t%i\t%i\t%i\t%i\n\n", "struct", m->a, m->b, m->c, m->someNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just one: don't.  Use a char array and reinterpret-cast or union it.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used C/C++. but I just saw this from Googling to see if a union was a possibility.
   union mix_t {
        long l;
        struct {
            short hi;
            short lo;
        } s;
     char c[4];
     } mix;

Comment: I'll bet if you check, `sizeof(myStruct)!=7`.

Comment: @Managu It should still be "serializable" as a 64-bit integer.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: `(unsigned long long) m->a << 56` puts `m->a` in the top eight bits, while `(num >> 56) & 0x0ff` get the top eight bits.

Comment: If you want a specifically 64-bit type, you should use `uint64_t` not `unsigned long long`. If you want a specifically 32-bit type, you should use `uint32_t` not `unsigned int`. et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

You should to do something like this:

```
class structured_uint64
{
    uint64_t data;
public:
    structured_uint64(uint64_t x = 0):data(x) {}
    operator uint64_t&() { return data; }
    unsigned uint8_t low_byte(size_t n) const { return data >> (n * 8); }
    void low_byte(size_t n, uint8_t val) {
        uint64_t mask = static_cast<uint64_t>(0xff) << (8 * n);
        data = (data & ~mask) | (static_cast<uint64_t>(val) << (8 * n));
    }
    unsigned uint32_t hi_word() const { return (data >> 24); }
    // et cetera
};
```

(there is, of course, lots of room for variation on the details of the interface and where among the 64 bits the constituents are placed)

Using different types to alias the same portion of memory is a generally bad idea. The thing is, it's very valuable for the optimizer to be able to use reasoning like:

> "Okay, I've read a `uint64_t` at the start of this block, and nowhere in the middle does the program write to any `uint64_t`s, therefore the value must be unchanged!"

which means it will get the wrong answer if you tried to change the value of the `uint64_t` object through a `uint32_t` reference. And as this is very dependent what optimizations are possible and done, it is actually pretty easy to never run across the problem in test cases, but see it in the real program you're trying to write -- and you'll spend forever trying to find the bug because you convinced yourself it's not this problem.

So, you really should do the insertion/extraction of the fields with bit twiddling (or intrinsics, if profiling shows that this is a performance issue and there are useful ones available) rather than trying to set up a clever struct.

If you *really* know what you're doing, you can make the aliasing work, I believe. But it should only be done if you *really* know what you're doing, and that includes knowing relevant rules from the standard inside and out (which I don't, and so I can't advise you on how to make it work). And even then you probably shouldn't do it.

Also, if you intend your integral types to be a specific size, you should *really* use the correct types. For example, never use `unsigned int` for an integer that is supposed to be exactly 32 bits. Instead use `uint32_t`. Not only is it self-documenting, but you won't run into a nasty surprise when you try to build your program in an environment where `unsigned int` is *not* 32 bits.

Comment: Naming both the getter an setter function to `low_byte` is not a good idea. In fact, drop `low_` as the function(s) can acces any byte. Also, `hi_word` is a bit pointless (and should shift 32). The `0xff` masks should have `ULL` suffixes etc. Apart from the implementation detains, the implementation is sound and endian-agnostic. +1

Comment: @Lindydancer: Aah! Good catch on the mask: I'm so used to writing a helper function and helper constants for this sort of thing with the right types that I forgot that detail in my trimmed down example. I agree the actual API should be reconsidered; I just picked the first thing that popped into my head since the important thing was the overall idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `union`.  Each element of a `union` occupies the same address space.  The `struct` is one element, the `unsigned long long` is another.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union data
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned char a;
        unsigned char b;
        unsigned char c;
        unsigned int d;
    } e;
    unsigned long long f;
};

int main()
{
    data dat;
    dat.f = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    dat.e.a = 1;
    dat.e.b = 2;
    dat.e.c = 3;
    dat.e.d = 4;
    printf("f=%016llX\n",dat.f);
    printf("%02X %02X %02X %08X\n",dat.e.a,dat.e.b,dat.e.c,dat.e.d);
    return 0;
}
```

Output, but note one byte of the original `unsigned long long` remains.  Compilers like to align data such as 4-byte integers on addresses divisible by 4, so three bytes, then a pad byte so the integer is at offset 4 and the `struct` has a total size of 8.

```
f=00000004FF030201
01 02 03 00000004
```

This can be controlled in compiler-dependent fashion.  Below is for Microsoft C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(push,1)
union data
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned char a;
        unsigned char b;
        unsigned char c;
        unsigned int d;
    } e;
    unsigned long long f;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main()
{
    data dat;
    dat.f = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    dat.e.a = 1;
    dat.e.b = 2;
    dat.e.c = 3;
    dat.e.d = 4;
    printf("f=%016llX\n",dat.f);
    printf("%02X %02X %02X %08X\n",dat.e.a,dat.e.b,dat.e.c,dat.e.d);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the `struct` occupies seven bytes now and the highest byte of the `unsigned long long` is now unchanged:

```
f=FF00000004030201
01 02 03 00000004
```

Comment: What you're proposing is formally undefined behavior (although I doubt that there is a compiler where it won't work).

Comment: @James: Oh I've definitely seen this sort of thing not work. The danger is in a code snippet where the compiler can optimize away a memory access, e.g. because it already knows the value of the `unsigned long long` from before, and it can't possibly have changed because you haven't written to any other `long long` objects. `unsigned char` in a union might be a special case for aliasing (I don't know), but that `unsigned int` is definitely a danger.

Comment: The point with undefined behaviour is that the only safe assumption is that it will stop working in the most inconvenient moment, when everyone who might have a clue that this `union` might be to blame has left the project.

Comment: -1: This is endian dependent. There is no need to write such code when you could use normal arithmetical operators to do the same in a endian-agnostic way.

Comment: @Hurkyl I've seen a compiler where it didn't work, but that was a long time ago.  Aliasing is always a bit dodgy, but I think all modern compilers _will_ recognize it when it is done through a `union`.  For historical reasons, if nothing else.  (Personally, I'd use shifting and masking for this sort of thing.)

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
static unsigned long long compress(char a, char b, char c, unsigned int someNumber)
{
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    x = x | a;
    x = x << 8;
    x = x | b;
    x = x << 8;
    x = x | c;
    x = x << 32;
    x = x | someNumber;
    return x;
}

myStruct * decompress(unsigned long long x)
{
    printBinary(x);
    myStruct * m = new myStruct();
    m->someNumber = x | 4294967296;
    x = x >> 32;
    m->c = x | 256;
    x = x >> 8;
    m->b = x | 256;
    x = x >> 8;
    m->a = x | 256;
    return m;
}
```